# Silverlight 4 missing from VS 2010

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

When I start a new Visual C# Silverlight project in the official release version (not the beta or the release candidate--the official release version) of Visual Studio 2010, I get only Silverlight 3 as an option in the Silverlight Version dropdown at the New Silverlight Application dialog box. I have installed SL 4, the SL4 tools for VS 2010, to no avail.

I am running Windows XP SP3.

Any ideas???

Thank you,
Jon

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight 4 is an out of band release.  It doesn't come with VS 2010 in the box.  Go here: [Silverlight 4](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/) to get the right version.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your quick reply. So "Silverlight 4 Tools RC2 for VS 2010" is all there is? I feel dumb because I expected SL4 Tools to be OUT OF RC status and in full production along with the official release of VS 2010. I don't like installing RC (release candidate) software on my machine and now it seems that I must, if I want to start playing around with SL4... Am I correct?

Do you know when it will go out of RC status and will be an official release?

Thanks again!

Comment: OK--I just finished trying your suggestion and it worked perfectly! Thank you. Once again, my only concern is installing "RC" software on my development machine... I have therefore installed to a VMWare virtual machine instead of the host.

Thanks again!

Comment: @iheartso: The thing with Release Candidates is that they are of a quality that MS believes is releasable. Most of the time there is some work to do even if all that means is changing the way the product is activated for licensing reasons. In some case however the release candidate needs no modification its good as is. I believe that is the case with the current Silverlight 4 Tools RC2. Its a release candiate in name only.